# Using latest Bulma Sass produce weird result in Angular 2 (4) components

Tags: css, angular, sass, bulma

If I break down a navigation menu (`navbar`) into components such as this:

```
<div class="navbar">
 <app-navbar-brand></app-navbar-brand>
 <app-navbar-menu></app-navbar-menu>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-brand">
  <!-- navbar-items -->
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
   <!-- angular components -->
 </div>
  <div class="navbar-end">
   <!-- angular components -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Some padding and other properties seem to work incorrectly in the menu.

If I keep the entire navbar in one component, I don't see this problem.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in Angular? Or is there something i've missed? It looks like the SASS is loaded in a weird way, but I cannot figure out why this is.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when using Bulma with Angular. The problem is because Bulma is built entirely using Flexbox. Angular component generated (pseudo) HTML tags, which are not using flexbox. I tried adjusting the component CSS style (i.e display, and width properties) seem to help, but not perfect. Hope that helps.